# Pedestal fan/refrigerator simulation

Tags: simulation, solar-energy

I want to simulate my PV system of 750 watts with 2* 100Ah batteries. My load is a pedestal fan and a refrigerator. I am confused as to how I can model a pedestal fan and refrigerator on Proteus/ Multisim/Simulink. As far as I have searched, I can represent fan by an AC motor, but are there any specifications I can use? I searched a lot about the fridge. Still clueless about that.  Need guidance.

Comment: Which type of simulation do you want to do?. In other words, what is the purpose of the simulation? Is it energy management (to see the energy and power balance in your system)? or it is a detailed simulation in which you want to implement all controllers and power electronic switches?

Comment: Yes, I am analyzing the system performance under different conditions. So I want to calculate the power losses, voltage drops etc. to improvise my design. So the simulation will be representing my system sketch pointing out voltages, currents and power levels at different points in the system.

Answer (score 0):

As per the details in your comment, Matlab is the best software to use.

To not start from zero, you can see the following in built example in Matlab-Simulink.

[image]

It is a small system contains PV, Battery and some loads. you can change the parameters as per your system.

To open the model type in Matlab workspace "power_microgrid" you will get this model.This [link](https://in.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/examples/simplified-model-of-a-small-scale-micro-grid.html) from Matlab gives a brief explanation of the system.

Now regarding the refrigerator and the fan, as you do not need to capture the dynamic behavior of the refrigerator and fan, you can plug their respective nominal power and voltage in the load blocks. However, If you want to capture the dynamic behavior, you can replace the load blocks in this example by asynchronous machine with constant mechanical load which represents the fan/compressor of the fan/refrigerator.